# Single file download is slow from every source, but speedtest result is fast

Tags: performance, internet, download, speed

I get 35Mbit download result from speedtest. 
But my maximum download speed can't go beyond 1MB/second. I tried every browser, many different download sources wetransfer etc.

Then I discovered if I try to download multiple files in the same time, I can reach my top speed in total which is around 4MB/second. It is like each download is capped at 1MB/second speed.

Also this problem happens on only on my desktop PC, my phone and laptop downloads the same files at full speed on the same router/connection.

Running Windows 10; tried disabling firewall, connected from ethernet/wifi both, updated LAN adapter and Wifi adapter drivers. Same problem each time.
Any ideas?

Comment: See if this works for you.....https://www.reddit.com/r/Seaofthieves/comments/87kzuo/how_to_speed_up_windows_10_downloads_its_got_a/

Comment: nope, that's only for microsoft updates / downloads in windows store.

Comment: So did you try it to see if it made any difference? Sometimes settings are not fully explained by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely QoS on your router which is limiting the max speed of each connection.

There are some download managers which are built get around this, they'll open multiple connections to a server and download different chunks of a file in parallel to speed up downloads.

Also, 4MB/s ~= 35Mb/s, so the max speed you are hitting is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the input. QoS is disabled on the router, plus I can download at full speed with different devices connected to the same router like my laptop etc.